# How can I perform search operation using raw sql query in django SQLITE

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to search string in the `STAT` table's `detection` field like below:

```
query = "select detection_class, stream_id, track_id, detection_time, " \
                    "frame_id" \
                    " FROM stats where  stream_id = %s "\
                    "detection_class like %%s%% group by track_id; "
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute(query,[stream_id, detection_class])
```

Here, when I give the word or some character which are contained in detection_class, it returns an error message like this`TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting')),`.
and also if I try like `detection_class=%s` it works properly when gives while word else it returns None.

Comment: Why ain't you use Django Qeuries?

Comment: @shahsawood this is company policy to use raw query only. This makes fast query execution and other benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string formatting when executing queries. Instead use a placeholder OR a named parameter.

```
query = """
SELECT detection_class, 
       stream_id, 
       track_id, 
       detection_time,
       frame_id
FROM stats
WHERE stream_id = :stream_id
AND detection_class LIKE :dclass 
GROUP BY track_id;
"""

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      params = {"stream_id": stream_id, "dclass": f"%{detection_class}%"}
      cursor.execute(query, params)
```

I believe it is also possible to do it using the placeholder method as well, as shown below.

```
query = """
SELECT detection_class, 
       stream_id, 
       track_id, 
       detection_time,
       frame_id
FROM stats
WHERE stream_id = ?
AND detection_class LIKE %?%
GROUP BY track_id;
"""

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute(query, (stream_id, detection_class,))
```